Is It Better To Query For Existing Or To Allow Unique Constraint To Fail Postgres
What is better, performance and convention wise, for checking if a value exists when inserting into a database.
I want to be able to insert a unique "random" string in with every record as a pseudo id of sorts. My first thought was to query the database for the string to determine if it exists first, but at a scale of 200,000,000 records at the moment, this has become quite CPU intensive.
This random string is generated in Python and passed to Postgres
(Records are processed at 100s a second, so you end up with many reads on the table per second)
My second thought was to just allow the unique constraint on the column to fail and if it fails, regenrate a new random string. Failures are not expected to be frequent, but it seems kind of dirty to do it that way.
Does anyone with more experience know what would be the best, fastest, or most correct way to do this?

The only definitive answer is the results of you testing each condition. But a thought experiment:  If you just insert Postgres must read the data (from an index) then either raise an exception if the value already exists. If  you select first your code can bypass inserting it the value exists, but if it does the insert must still do exactly  the same (although the result pf the select may be still be in memory and no physical I/O needed.

@Belayer yea after extended though about it i came to the same conclusion, and it got me wondering if there is a third option/ pattern for this.


allow the unique constraint on the column to fail and if it fails, regenrate a new random string. Failures are not expected to be frequent, but it seems kind of dirty to do it that way.

I don't think there's anything inherently dirty about unique violation exception handling, or using exception handling to accommodate your app logic in general. Things like explicit locks  (select..for update nowait, pg_try_advisory_lock()) and serializable commits are even designed so that you catch and re-try - these are just examples of controlling flow based on exceptions. You don't need them here since that insert already grabs a RowExclusiveLock lock on the corresponding index and table entries, implicitly.
That's not to say I'm completely disregarding the DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl idea - my point here is it has its place when you communicate between two separate systems, your app and the db.
That being said, you might consider insert..on conflict do nothing and reading the status/command tag/label of the result which should tell you how many rows were successfully inserted - if it says 0, generate a new one and try again. Logically, it's the same as handling the exception, but it saves the  db-side overhead of an actual exception so it should perform a bit better.
If you don't want to deal with the command tag, you can count(*) rows you get from insert..returning to get the row count, in an actual result row:
demo at db<>fiddle
with inserted as (
  insert into your_table (your_unique_column)
  values (value_from_the_app)
  on conflict do nothing
  returning 1)
select count(*) from inserted;

As @Belayer pointed out, probing with select will effectively cost you pretty much the same as letting an insert fail (except the cost of raising the exception, if you don't just read the 0 off the command tag).
If the select finds no conflicting value and gives you the green light to run your insert, that subsequent insert will re-check it anyways - so you might as well let the insert handle both.

Im not familiar with the insert on conflict commands, although i have done that through Django's orm as an aside. My thought was to fail the whole query and then try again. but with the on conflict block it seems like i could generate x number of random fields for the initial insert, and then an additional x number for the on conflict part? maybe im just mis understanding it. Right now i simply have been using it to ignore failures for bulk opperations.

@Bigbob556677 "generate x number of random fields for the initial insert, and then an additional x number for the on conflict part" sounds like you're describing on conflict do update, which you don't want. You do want to fail, or rather discard/disregard/ignore the insert you just attempted, if it was found to conflict with something that's already in the table. My point is that on conflict do nothing will save you the exception cost, while communicating the same thing - it'll still say 0 rows got inserted, so it must've failed, just without causing all the exception fuss

The overhead of handling the exception in Python is inconsequential compared to doing the insert and communicating with the database. This is an appropriate use of exceptions, the insert failing is an exceptional case. Unique constraints are very simple, there's no need to reinvent this wheel. Definitely don't use a lock.

@Schwern Thanks for taking a look and apologies for a lengthy response. 1) From Python's perspective, there's zero difference between what type or which part of the response you base your logic. I'm referring to the db-side overhead - it's cheaper for the db to not throw exceptions. I added a an edit to clarify that.

2) I pretty much open by saying it is an appropriate use of exceptions, although I wouldn't insist on calling that an exceptional case. Conceptually, the user does expect a collision and I'd argue the rarity of the event doesn't warrant qualifying a case as an exception either, but I guess you can define your criteria of exceptional rather arbitrarily.

3) The locks were given as an example of something leaning on exception-based flow control, not a suggestion to use them here. There's no need for an explicit lock because the insert already comes with an implicit one: make a table with a unique column, open 2 sessions, issue an insert of the same value from each - one of them will hang and pg_locks will show locks on the table and the index behind the unique constraint. - added in an edit as well.

4) No wheels, no reinventions. Maybe moving the insert count from the command tag to the output row might be a bit pointless - it's already there, so moving it is only for convenience.
5) As per 3) above - you can't not use a lock - it's there whether you want it or not. The explicit ones were just examples of exception-driven control - again, just examples.

@Zegarek I will add to you second point and your hesitation to promote DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl. Its actually (in a lot of cases) more idiomatic to use exceptions in flow control. For example EAFP. This is of course a broad brush, but is a totally valid way to do it.


What is better, performance wise...

If you check then insert PostgreSQL has to check twice. Once when you select, and once to check for uniqueness when you insert. However, this is using an index so the size of the table does not matter. And you're doing two queries vs one, queries come with a lot of overhead.
But, there's a more important consideration than performance. Read on.

My second thought was to just allow the unique constraint on the column to fail and if it fails, regenrate a new random string. Failures are not expected to be frequent, but it seems kind of dirty to do it that way.

That's exactly how you do it, except you use a random number big enough to basically be impossible to have a conflict.

Querying then inserting invites a race condition. Consider what happens when two processes try to query and insert the same ID at the same time.



Process 1
Process 2




select x




select x


not found




not found


insert x




insert x


success




conflict



It's better to simply insert the value, let the database check for uniqueness, and try again if it fails with a unique constraint violation. You want checking and inserting to be one single operation so nobody else can do anything between checking and inserting.

Incidentally, if you want a unique identifier that's all but guaranteed not to conflict, use a UUIDv4. This is basically a 122 bit random number or 5316911983139663491615228241121378304 possibilities. It's so large a conflict is essentially impossible.
PostgreSQL has a UUID type and a function to make a UUIDv4. Use that for your primary key, id uuid primary key default gen_random_uuid().
This is better than inserting a random number from Python, now anyone working with the database can safely insert rows.
Demonstration.

Im currently using something similar to uuid and encoding that to A-Za-z0-9 and is 12 digits long, its already quite un expected to have conflicts. But i do like the idea of using the database to generate that, I cant assign it to a primary key (just because of the product itself, it wouldnt work) unless i could roll out my own function to generate it in postgres. which is a different venture.

@Bigbob556677 12 hex digits is 16**12 or about 3e14 (about 300 trillion). With 2e8 (200 million) rows you have roughly 1 in a million chance of a conflict. This sounds good until you realize you'd have about 100 conflicts so far. A UUIDv4 is 5e36, With 200 million rows there's a 1-in-2e28 chance of conflict, or effectively 0. It can be stored in just 16 bytes. It can be converted to a hexadecimal value for display. The primary key doesn't have to be the same as the business ID; you can have a simple integer primary key and also a unique, random business ID. Yes, you can write your own func.

Would it not be 56**12 for A-Za-z0-9, thats 56 unique characters, at 12 digits long?(its just a random string/ slug)
Also to add, the values are only valid for a month, at which point they are dumped. So maybe im worried about an issue id never actually face in practice.

@Bigbob556677 You're right, 56**12 or about 1e21. That's better, and harder for someone to brute force. All you need to do is insert and if there's a unique constraint violation try again with a fresh number.
